# BUG MODAL DO BOOTSTRAP NO IOS

Tags: modal, iphone

O modal funciona perfeitamente quando chamado em dispositivos android, ou em descktops, porém quando é utilizado pelo iphone ele simplesmente se estende até o fim da tela como se não tivesse fim. ALGUÉM PODERIA ME AJUDAR, O QUE PODE SER ESSA BRUXA?

A IMAGEM A BAIXO INFORMA COMO ELE ESTÁ NO IPHONE
E O CODIGO DO MODAL E DO "`<a>`" que chama o modal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<button style="vertical-align:middle;">  
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_Pessoa"  style="margin-left:10px;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;color:inherit;">TESTE/a>
 </button>


<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Pessoa" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Modal_Pessoa_Label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-left" id="exampleModalLabel">Buscar Cliente</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <iframe src="" name="iframe_pessoa" id="iframe_pessoa" style="border:none;" height="390" width="100%"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancelar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="">Usar esta pessoa</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que faltou você adicionar na sua pergunta as tags [tag:twitter-bootstrap] e [tag:css]

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="" name="iframe_pessoa" id="iframe_pessoa" style="border:none;" height="390" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Reparei que tens height 390 talvez o problema possa ser esse!

Podes sempre meter 50%.

Boa sorte.

Comment: não, não resolveu.